# prettier urls with nextjs routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, api-design

I'm building out a new marketing site for my company using `next.js`, and I'm running into an issues with URLS. Essentially, I've built a custom API route to access data from our internal database, using Prisma:

**getAllDealers.ts**

```
import Cors from 'cors';
import { prisma } from 'lib/prisma';
import { NextApiResponse, NextApiRequest, NextApiHandler } from 'next';

const cors = Cors({
  methods: ['GET', 'HEAD'],
});

function runMiddleware(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse, fn: any) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(req, res, (result: any) => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        return reject(result);
      }

      return resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

const getDealers: NextApiHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { method } = req;

  await runMiddleware(req, res, cors);
  const dealers = await prisma.crm_dealers.findMany({
    where: {
      active: {
        not: 0,
      },
    },
  });

  switch (method) {
    case 'GET':
      res.status(200).send({ dealers, method: method });
      break;
    case 'PUT':
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'sorry, we only accept GET requests', method: method });
      break;
    default:
      res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET']);
      res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`);
  }
};

export default getDealers;
```

And I've built a route to access individual dealers:

**getSingleDealer.ts**

```
import Cors from 'cors';
import { prisma } from 'lib/prisma';
import { NextApiResponse, NextApiRequest, NextApiHandler } from 'next';

const cors = Cors({
  methods: ['GET', 'HEAD'],
});

function runMiddleware(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse, fn: any) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(req, res, (result: any) => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        return reject(result);
      }

      return resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

const getDealerById: NextApiHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  await runMiddleware(req, res, cors);
  const dealer = await prisma.crm_dealers.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: Number(req.query.id),
    },
  });

  res.status(200).send({ dealer, method: req.method });
};

export default getDealerById;
```

I can use my `getSingleDealer` function in `getServerSideProps` like so:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params }: Params) => {
  const { uid } = params;

  const { dealer } = await getSingleDealer('api/dealer', uid);

  return {
    props: { dealer },
  };
};
```

And this works just fine. What I need to do though is prettify my URLS. Right now, the way to access a singular dealer's page is `dealers/1` with 1 being whatever the ID of the dealer is. I want to have that URL be a string, like `dealers/sacramento-ca` (that location is also served up in the API) while still accessing the API on the basis of the `id` so it's searching for an integer, rather than a string. Is that possible within next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd handle the routing in your client with [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) similarly to what you are doing now.  To do so, you need to configure your [dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) file or folder name to match your desired format.

Example folder structures are:

`pages > dealers > [dealer].tsx` = /dealers/sacramento-ca

`pages > dealers > [location] > index.tsx` = /dealers/sacramento-ca

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params }: Params) => {
  const { uid } = params;
  const { dealer } = await getSingleDealer('api/dealer', uid);

  if (!dealer ) {
    return { notFound: true }
  }

  return {
    props: { 
     ...dealer,
     location: 'sacramento-ca', // object key must match your dynamic [folder or file's name]
    },
  };
};
```

All dynamic URL parts must be included as a key in the return.

`pages > dealers > [state] > index.tsx [city].tsx` = /dealers/ca/sacramento

```
return {
  props: {
   ...dealer,
   city: 'sacramento',
   state: 'ca',
  },
};
```

Here is a [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/prefetching-dynamic-routing-next-js/) detailing what you will need to do. It's important to note that sometimes it's desirable to use a [catch all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes) to simplify searching and deeply nested dynamic routes.

Comment: I've used catch all routes before, no idea why I didn't think of that. Thanks!